# External sensors in Monkey C?

Tags: cadence, heartrate, monkeyc

I’m currently trying to program a Watch App in Monkey C and I have no idea how to create a function that adds heart rate and cadence obtained from external sensors on the bike. Also I don’t know in which .mc I’m supposed to implement it.